# Map environment variabels in JSON with JQ inside docker

Tags: json, bash, docker, jq

I have been banging my head against the wall for 8 hours now, but cant seem to fix this issue.

I have a json looking like this:

```
{
 "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
 "tasks.max": 1,
 "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
 "key.converter.schemas.enable": false,
 "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
 "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "CONNECTOR_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL",
 "value.converter.schemas.enable": true,
 "topics": "CONNECTOR_TOPICS",
 "name": "CONNECTOR_NAME",
 "connection.uri": "CONNECTOR_MONGODB_CONNECTION_URI",
 "database": "CONNECTOR_MONGODB_DATABASE_NAME",
 "collection": "CONNECTOR_MONGODB_COLLECTION_NAME",
 "max.num.retries": 1,
 "retries.defer.timeout": 5000,
 "errors.log.include.messages": true,
 "document.id.strategy": 
 "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.ProvidedInKeyStrategy",
 "document.id.strategy.overwrite.existing": true,
 "delete.on.null.values": true,
 "post.processor.chain": 
 "com.az.ip.dmdp.commons.mongodb.kafka.connect.BsonOidProcessor, 
  com.az.ip.dmdp.commons.mongodb.kafka.connect.BsonTimestampProcessor",
 "writemodel.strategy": 
 "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.UpdateOneTimestampsStrategy",
 "transforms": "hoistKeyOid, hoistKeyId",
 "transforms.hoistKeyOid.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HoistField$Key",
 "transforms.hoistKeyOid.field": "oid",
 "transforms.hoistKeyId.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HoistField$Key",
 "transforms.hoistKeyId.field": "_id"
}
```

Im trying to replace the values starting with CONNECTOR using jq. I found this neet little trick: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657466/how-to-update-given-environment-variable-values-in-json

It works perfectly, with a minor tweak in my terminal. As long as the vars are set in my terminal

```
jq 'with_entries( .value = ($ENV."\(.value)" // .value ) )' device-connectorbody.json
```

But when i add the same row inside a bash script that executes inside a docker container, i get the following error message:

```
jq: error: ENV/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
with_entries( .value = ($ENV."\(.value)" // .value ) )                        
jq: 1 compile error
```

From what i can understand about the error, it seems like it can't expand the ENV variabel, but WHY?!

If anyone have any idea on what i'm doing wrong, please help.

Comment: Which version of jq is present inside your container? If the one in your host is new enough to have `ENV` but the one in the container is not, there's your problem -- it's a relatively recent feature.

Comment: Good idea. Will check asap.

Comment: Did you export the variables or just declare them?

Comment: Export. It was the version as Charles pointed out. It’s always the most obvious answer. Will update with his answer shortly!

Comment: btw, if you want to export things only for one command, `var1=value1 var2=value2 somecommand` done _as a single command_ (no newlines or other command separators) will export `var1` and `var2` in the environment of `somecommand` without modifying the environment of other/later commands.

Comment: BTW, answers should be added as answers, not question updates. Feel free to use the "Add an Answer" button yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple enough. Needed to have the 1.6 version inside docker. To be able to do that i needed to install epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm before installing jq. Otherwise it installed 1.5 version of jq. So thanks Charles Duffy!